# Create data container via Azure Machine learning REST API

Tags: azure, machine-learning, curl, azure-machine-learning-service

I understand API is in preview but maybe someone can help me out here .

I am trying to create `Data container` as its described in [AML REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/data-containers/create-or-update#datacontainer)

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/resourceGroups/{{resourceGroupName}}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{{workspaceName}}/data/abc?api-version=2021-03-01-preview' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"properties": { "description": "string",
"tags": { },
"properties": {}
}
}'
```

I receive `400` status code with message

```
Error setting value to 'Description' on 'Microsoft.MachineLearning.ManagementFrontEnd.Contracts.V20210301Preview.Assets.DataContainer'."
```

after removing Description which should be optional

```
DataContainers_CreateOrUpdate is not supported
```

How can I create Dataset with local files? I cannot use UI. There it works and I can receive it with GET list method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a dataset from local file, you can use az ml cli. Use following command from a powershell:

```
az ml dataset create --file data.yaml --resource-group "your-resource-group" --workspace-name "your-ws-name"
```

data.yaml

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/dataset.schema.json
name: local-file-example
description: Dataset created from local file.
local_path: data/titanic.csv
```

See [az yaml schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-yaml-dataset) and [az dataset cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml/dataset?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: thank you, but usage of CLI is not an option. It might be possible to use SDK but i need to stick with API because of Architecture...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like API version 2021-03-01-preview is not working properly for dataset operations. By reverse-engineering the az CLI command mentioned by qiax using the --debug option I could see that the endpoint used by the CLI is the following:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group}/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/{workspace}/datasets/{dataset-name}/versions/1/?api-version=2021-10-01
```

Here's an example of a valid request body for that endpoint (it seems like it's the same as the Create Or Update Data Version endpoint shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/data-versions/create-or-update)):

```json
    {
    "properties": {
        "isAnonymous": false,
        "paths": [
            {
                "file": "foo/"
            }
        ],
        "properties": {},
        "tags": {}
    }
```